# How to rename RavenDB database using ClientAPI?

Tags: database, rename, ravendb4

Is there a way of renaming a RavenDB database from code by using ClientAPI and operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database cannot be renamed from code.

You need to 'soft' delete the database and then recreate it on the same path with a new name.

See full explanation in: [RavenDB Book - Renaming a database](https://github.com/ravendb/book/blob/v4.0/Ch18/Ch18.md#renaming-a-database)